# Vertex AI Pipeline quota aiplatform.googleapis.com/restricted_image_training_tpu_v3_pod

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-pipeline

I'm getting started with creating a tuned model. I've got my training data in a .jsonl file, uploaded to a bucket, everything checks out. I've run the tuning 3 times and every time it fails on step 7/8.

```
com.google.cloud.ai.platform.common.errors.AiPlatformException: code=RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, message=The following quota metrics exceed quota limits: aiplatform.googleapis.com/restricted_image_training_tpu_v3_pod, cause=null; Failed to create custom job.Project number: 643054741456, Job id: 7035574795022368768, Task id: -2160728365068189696, Task name: large-language-model-tuner, Task state: DRIVER_SUCCEEDED, Execution name: projects/643054741456/locations/europe-west4/metadataStores/default/executions/6209974609820216962; Failed to create external task or refresh its state. Task:Project number: 643054741456, Job id: 7035574795022368768, Task id: -2160728365068189696, Task name: large-language-model-tuner, Task state: DRIVER_SUCCEEDED, Execution name: projects/643054741456/locations/europe-west4/metadataStores/default/executions/6209974609820216962; Failed to handle the pipeline task. Task: Project number: 643054741456, Job id: 7035574795022368768, Task id: -2160728365068189696, Task name: large-language-model-tuner, Task state: DRIVER_SUCCEEDED, Execution name: projects/643054741456/locations/europe-west4/metadataStores/default/executions/6209974609820216962
```

I followed the steps here: [Vertax AI pipeline quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73368320/vertax-ai-pipeline-quota) with no luck.

I searched the quotas and for the quota listed in the error message, it says I'm at 0%.
[image]

It also shows no quotas are over 90%.

The docs say that these pipelines only run on us-central1, when I inspect the quota for `restricted_image_training_tpu_v3_pod` it says my quota is 0. I can request an increase to 1 but I would have thought the docs would mention you can't get started without that.
[image]

Here's what the pipeline looks like:
[image]

Comment: Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/models/tune-models#quota) help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew I've read those docs, the confusing part is that it says you can only run the tuning model in us-central1 but the resources needed for that job are only available in europe-west4. If you can figure out how to configure it correctly, please let me know.

Comment: Based on my understanding you can give the tuning job location as "europe-west4" and the tuned model location as "us-central1".

Comment: I'm having the EXACT same issue. Did you find a solution? I will try @kiranmathew's suggestion for now

Comment: @kiranmathew can you post steps with screenshots on how to do that? When using the vertex AI UI it doesn't let you configure much, are you using the cli instead?

Comment: Hi @santeko,have you tried in the `europe-west4` region?

Comment: @kiranmathew have you read the docs that say you can only setup vertex ai in us-central1? If you can show with screenshots steps to set it up with workarounds, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

To add on [kiran matthew's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76302788/vertex-ai-pipeline-quota-aiplatform-googleapis-com-restricted-image-training-tpu#:%7E:text=Does%20this%20link,kiran%20mathew) answer,

Since the model uses 64 cores of TPU v3, you may submit a [quota increase request](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota_detail/view_manage#requesting_higher_quota) in multiples of 64 (eg. a multiplier of 64 (1 job 64, 2 concurrent jobs 128) under Restricted image training TPU V3 pod cores per region quota.

Comment: I reached out to GCP and they said they cannot increase the quota because the resource `TPU v3` isn't available in the region the docs say you have to run Vertex Ai (us-west), you can only increase the quote in europe-west4. Looking for someone who's figured out how to get it to run to share their steps.